# How to display <form:errors> outside <form:form> in Spring?

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, error-handling

I'm new to Spring and I've been having some trouble trying to show a form errors.

I have the following form:

```
<form:form action="loginform.html" commandName="loginForm" onsubmit="goWait();">
<table><tr>
           <td>User Name: </td>
           <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
           <td>Password: </td>
           <td><form:password path="password"/> </td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
             <input type="submit" value="Login" style="butt-login">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>                                                        
</form:form>
```

The form, as can be seen, is backed by a `LoginForm` Bean that validates it.

I want to show all the errors from the validation, outside this form. Something like this:

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li><form:errors path="userName"/></li>
      <li><form:errors path="password"/></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This div should be outside the , so I can't use the  tag.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you put the div inside the form but outside the table?

Comment: @BheshGurung sadly no, I have to fix the form in an old template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just capture the html produced by form:errors and display it somewhere after the form:

```
<form:form ...>
    <c:set var="err">
        <form:errors path="*" element="div" id="err" cssClass="hidden" />
    </c:set>
</form:form>

....

<c:out value="${err}" />
```

If you want to show the errors *before* the form, you can do that with a bit of jQuery

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can user form:errors tag outside form:form tag

```
<form:errors path="yourBindedObject.*" />
<form:form action="loginform.html" commandName="loginForm" onsubmit="goWait();">
<table><tr>
           <td>User Name: </td>
           <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
           <td>Password: </td>
           <td><form:password path="password"/> </td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
             <input type="submit" value="Login" style="butt-login">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>                                                        
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all errors associated with any fields just pass a star to the `path` attribute.

```
<form:errors path="*" />
```

But if you want to show global error messages just pass an empty string:

```
<form:errors path="" />
```

More information related: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-errors-tag-example/

Comment: Can I use <form:errors> tags outside <form:form> </form:form> tags?

Comment: @ChristianVielma not. Bad me, I forgot the main purpose of your question... In the past I remember to face this situation, but the solution was not clean, but using a dirty trick inspecting the session with JSTL.